# python discord.py как сделать счетчик

Tags: python, discord.py, async-await, асинхронность

В моем боте есть команда и мне нужно сделать счетчик, который будет подсчитывать сколько раз нажали на кнопку. Подскажите как хранить много дынных в одной переменной, то есть как хранить данные разных пользователей в одных переменно, например: есть 3 пользователя и нужно чтобы в этом переменной хранились разные данные у первого пользователя 10 очков, у второго 20 и тд. То есть чтобы для каждого пользователя эта переменная была своя

Comment: SQL в помощь...

Comment: @xZartsust, я тоже об этом думал, но я не хотел лишний раз использовать sql, так как у меня sqllite, а данные придется записывать достаточно часто, так что  sql мне не подходит

Comment: Так в чем проблема сделать в sqllite?